# Checkbox toggles the page view

Tags: javascript, html

I want to offer the user an "Advanced Search" page that toggles on or off with a checkbox.  I made a div that's layered over the rest of the page and used the checkbox like so:

```
style.display = "none"
style.display = "block"
```

This works pretty well and because what I want is basically a modal dialog, it makes sense to me.

I added a "Reset" button which should clear all the fields, then present the "Advanced Search" page again.  I don't know how to accomplish all that.  I have two ideas, but neither is working:

1. Reset the session variables for search terms, then somehow tell the
   refreshed page to have the checkbox on.
2. Instead of showing or hiding a div, use a dedicated "Advanced Search" page.  This page is the root URL with a parameter ?search=true.  The checkbox toggles between the URL with and without the parameter.  Seems easier to control.

My attempts to use this kind of code for solution #2 haven't worked:

```
function ModalPage() {
    if( self.location == location ) 
         { self.location = "?search=true"; }
    else { self.location = location; }
    // (some attempts looked less silly than this...)of #2
}
```

Your solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about storing that option in session then loading the page again.  On pageload, you could check that session variable and, if set, then have the checkmark checked.

Comment: I can set the checkbox as checked, but that does not fire the script.  Maybe I simply need to set the style.display attribute.

Comment: Oh, you've got it firing on the click?  Yeah, I'd just set the style.display attribute as well -- the page isn't going to see it as a change if you do it programmatically.

Comment: Heh ... I just got a little frustrated and quit trying as I ought to.  But I also needed some reassurance.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that you have a simple "Search page" and an "Advanced search" page? 
Or you have only one page, with the advanced search functions showed and hidden following the checkbox click?

In the second case, you can add a new javascript function called "reset" and associate the function to the reset button:

```
<input type="button" id="resetButton" onclick="reset();" value="Reset"/>
```

In the new javascript "reset" function, you can make the two operations: reset all the fields, and a show the Advanced Search component

```
function reset() {
    //reset all the fields
    ....

    document.getElementById(YOUR_ADVANCED_SEARCH_ID).style.display = "block";
}
```

In the first case, the reset function can simply redirect to the advanced search page, something like

```
location.href = "advancedSearchPage.XXX";
```

Comment: Comprehensive answer, looks like.  Thanks much -- I may refer to this again.  Up-vote.